# excel vba select second to last character in a cell

Tags: string, excel, format, cell, vba

I thought this would be simple but can't find the solution anywhere! I am writing a macro to insert a red tick (or down arrow) after the existing text in a cell.

```
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ActiveCell & " P "
```

The P needs to be formatted bold, red and Wingdings 2.  It needs a space after it in case text is added at the end in the future.

No problem if it is before the text:

```
With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=2, length:=1).Font
```

How can I select it when it is the second to last character in the cell?

(Or is there any other way to achieve this?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
With ActiveCell.Characters(ActiveCell.Characters.count - 1, 1).Font
  .name = "Wingdings 2"
  .Bold = True
End With
```

Comment: You were just waiting for a question now ?

Comment: @ShaiRado lol, actually I am reading an excellent book, but u know... SO is always "on" :P.

Comment: Perfect- Thank you SO much!  I wasn't expecting an answer so soon... enjoy your book! :-)  I see it is already marked as an answer, should I do anything else?

Comment: @Piecevcake Glad to help. Actually you need to click the grey chekmark to turn it green and mark the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Oh dear, I have just seen that this macro removes all other character formatting in the cell!

Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @Piecevcake This piece of code shouldn't alter any formatting of other chcracters in the cell. It might be due to something else.

Comment: @ A.S.H where the macro is run on a cell where some characters in the cell bolded, others red, and a previous wingdings tick in the cell, all of those character formatting is removed, and it ends up with plain text, P, red tick. 
It happened when the line     "ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ActiveCell & " P "" is run, and I suppose I can see why... it only adds the value of the cell, not the formatting...

Comment: @Piecevcake yeah, changing the value will loose some of the old formatting because all the new text will have the same format, that of the overall cell. I think it's an excellent subject for another question.

Comment: @A.S.H maybe too big for another question!  But will give it a go :-)

Comment: Question posted at <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45261166/excel-vba-add-formatted-symbol-to-text-in-a-cell-keeping-character-formats-of>

Answer (score 0):

My final code for inserting a tick after text in a cell, with an unformatted space after it allowing normal text to be added after it later (incorporating the answer above and the answer from :

```
Sub I___TickRedAFTERText_KeepsOtherCharFormatting()

ActiveCell.Characters(ActiveCell.Characters.Count + 1, 1).Insert (" P ")

'format the new character but not the added spaces
     With ActiveCell.Characters(ActiveCell.Characters.Count - 1, 1).Font 'second to last character in cell
        .Name = "Wingdings 2"
        .Bold = True
        .Color = -16776961
    End With
End Sub
```