# Add formatted symbol after text, keeping character formats of pre-existing text

Tags: excel, vba, string, formatting

I want to insert a red tick (or down arrow) after the existing text in a cell.

How do I insert the characters and *retain* the pre-existing character formats in the cell? Where I have bold, underlined or coloured only some of the words inside those cells.

The generally suggested code reverts all customised character formatting of the original cell contents to the cell font format.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ActiveCell & " P "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My final code to insert a tick after text in a cell, with an unformatted space after it, allowing normal text to be added after it later (incorporating the answer above, corrected, and and [excel vba select second to last character in a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45256928/excel-vba-select-second-to-last-character-in-a-cell/69077850#69077850)):

```
Sub I___TickRedAFTERText_KeepsOtherCharFormatting()

ActiveCell.Characters(ActiveCell.Characters.Count + 1, 1).Insert (" P ") 'down arrow is " â "

'format the new character but not the added spaces
     With ActiveCell.Characters(ActiveCell.Characters.Count - 1, 1).Font 'second to last character in cell
        .Name = "Wingdings 2"
        .Bold = True
        .Color = -16776961 'from recorded macro
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**: Using `ActiveCell.Value` or `ActiveCell.Formula` will indeed change any SPECIAL formatting you previously had (my initial post overlooked that). However, as your research indirectly displayed, you can change the text by using character.insert, but you need to have the character length of where to insert to avoid changing your custom formatting.

Try this instead of value or formula setting.

```
ActiveCell.Characters(ActiveCell.Characters.Count + 1, 1).Insert (" P ")
```

Then you proceed to update the second to last character using a similar approach (this is essentially editing 1 character before the last character).

```
With ActiveCell.Characters(ActiveCell.Characters.Count -1, Length:=1).Font
        .Name = "Wingdings 2"
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Size = 10
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ColorIndex = 1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
End With
```

Comment: @ PGCodeRider  that code returned error  404  object required.
Modifying it to
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & " P "
removed the pre-existing characters formatting in the cell. My question is how to retain that pre-existing character formatting?

Comment: @Piecevcake, sorry I missed that. I'll update. Small change.

Comment: @Piecevcake. The first error you received was because I thought you had defined `Cell`. I changed the code to use `ActiveCell` instead. No errors like that should persist.

Comment: the first line ActiveCell.Characters(Len(ActiveCell.Value), Length:=1).Insert (" P ")

 returns an error message syntax error?  Is there something I need to add?

Comment: @Piecevcake Dang... my fault. `ActiveCell.Characters(Len(ActiveCell.Value), 1).Insert (" P ")` I will update (note the missing :=

Comment: It's looking good!  Just cuts off the last character in the cell. I tried changing `1`to 0, then it strangely keeps the last character and inserts the insertion before it!  -1 also cuts off the last character.  SOLUTION:      `ActiveCell.Characters(ActiveCell.Characters.Count - -1, 1).Insert (" P ") 'Adds AFTER existing text!`  Update your formula and I will tick it, many thanks.  And do I get a point??? :-)

PS I am not formatting the spaces so using      With ActiveCell.Characters(ActiveCell.Characters.Count - 1, 1).Font

Comment: Heck yeah you get a point! I am not sure the difference between our count methods, but I believe you. I think your first formula has a redundant subtraction sign correct? See my version, and thanks for tick! :)

Comment: `ActiveCell.Characters(ActiveCell.Characters.Count - -1, 1).Insert (" P ")` doesn't work without the 2 minus signs.  The first is a separator.  Also `With ActiveCell.Characters(ActiveCell.Characters.Count - 1, 1).Font ` needs to be updated in your code or text cannot be added properly before or after the tick.  Thank YOU for the tick! :)

Comment: Ehh... I don't think so. That is a numeric position, not a separator. I think the correct syntax should actually be +1 but you have achieved that via the scenic route of -(-1). Test with `ActiveCell.Characters(ActiveCell.Characters.Count +1, 1).Insert (" P ")` and see if you get the desired result. I'm guessing you will as it would explain all of the previous differences. Updating answer... again! What a great Saturday night! :)

Comment: While we are on the subject, are you able to advise the code to insert at the beginning of the cell?  Thankyou!

Comment: excel just crashed so will check your code later- though I did try 1 and 0 without a + or - and error was returned.  I will check the +

Comment: @ pgSystemTester, `ActiveCell.Characters(ActiveCell.Characters.Count + 1, 1).Insert (" P ")`  works, and for the format selection I have `With ActiveCell.Characters(ActiveCell.Characters.Count - 1, 1)`.  You need to update your answer :)