# Change text color as it's appended?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-project

I'm going to be generating some large excel cell values by appending MS Project tasks info to each other, and then I'll be calculating if a certain task has changed since the last report. I need to color just the changed tasks in the cell, but it will be in a long string with lots of other tasks. It would be really nice if I could change the color of tasks as I append them.

I'm thinking I've got to use some sort of 'With' statement, but I don't where to start.

```
With cell
    .FutureFormat red
    .Value = .Value & "abc"
End With
```

Or something like

```
Stringthing = "ABC"
Stringthing.Format = red
Cell.value = cell.value & Stringthing
```

Comment: You *can* use the .Characters collection to add new text without changing the formatting of existing content, but I seem to recall it becomes somewhat useless once the length of text exceeds 256 characters.

Comment: @TimWilliams Just length of the text being added, or the text of the cell? The text I'm appending should never be that long, I'm just adding a bunch of them.

Comment: The length of the whole text in the cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AppendStringAndColorize()
    Dim str As String
    str = "abc"

    Dim cell As Range
    Set cell = Range("A1")

    Dim CellLength As Long
    CellLength = Len(cell.Value)

    With cell
        .Value = .Value & str
        .Characters(Start:=CellLength + 1, Length:=Len(str)).Font.Color = vbRed
    End With
End Sub
```

you first need to remember the length of the original value as start point to colorize the characters after that value.

---

To keep the old colors:

```
Public Sub AppendStringAndColorizeKeepingOldColors()
    Dim str As String
    str = "abc"

    Dim cell As Range
    Set cell = Range("A1")

    Dim CharList() As Variant
    Dim CurrentColor As Double
    CurrentColor = cell.Characters(1, 1).Font.Color

    Dim iColor As Long 'color change counter
    iColor = 1
    ReDim CharList(1 To 2, 1 To 1) As Variant
    CharList(1, iColor) = CurrentColor

    Dim CellLength As Long
    CellLength = cell.Characters.Count

    'analyze colors and save into array
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To CellLength
        If cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color <> CurrentColor Then
            CurrentColor = cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color
            iColor = iColor + 1
            ReDim Preserve CharList(1 To 2, 1 To iColor)
            CharList(1, iColor) = CurrentColor
        End If
        CharList(2, iColor) = CharList(2, iColor) + 1
    Next i

    'change cell value (append only!)
    cell.Value = cell.Value & str

    're-write colors
    Dim ActChar As Long
    ActChar = 1
    For i = LBound(CharList) To UBound(CharList, 2)
        cell.Characters(Start:=ActChar, Length:=CharList(2, i)).Font.Color = CharList(1, i)
        ActChar = ActChar + CharList(2, i)
    Next i

    'color for new appended string
    cell.Characters(Start:=CellLength + 1, Length:=Len(str)).Font.Color = vbYellow 'desired color

End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't `.Value = .Value & str` would wipe out any color formatting already applied to that cell? I was going to originally try this approach as well.

Comment: @BigBen well that's something different now. As far as I know there is no possibilty to keep partial colorization of characters when changing the value of the cell. It might work by analyzing the original cell value and color character wise, remember that in a variable array (or something), then changing the value and recolorize everything. But this looks a bit cumbersome. Maybe you should re-think your approach completely and you can go another way.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I didn't want to try doing, but feared would be necessary given " it will be in a long string with lots of other tasks". +1 for a good starting point at least.

Comment: @BigBen Well, Excel's strength is definitely not using different formats inside one cell, that's just not what is was made for. Its strength is calculation. You might reconsider if it is the right tool for that, or write yourself that cumbersome workaround.

Comment: btw I didn't ask the original question :) Not sure how motivated I am to write that cumbersome workaround, which the exact description of what it would be.

Comment: Would I want to use a 2D array to store start and stop lengths and then go back and iterate through the array on the cell to change the colors after the fact?

Comment: You can use the Characters approach to add text without disturbing the existing formatting.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45261166/excel-vba-add-formatted-symbol-to-text-in-a-cell-keeping-character-formats-of

Comment: See my edit this should even work for longer text to preserve the colors. No idea how fast/slow it is. Probably a good idea to make a function out of it accepting a range and TextToAppend as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you add new text without disturbing the existing formatting.

**NOTE:** this approach  is only good up to about 250 characters total length.  Not sure if there's any way after you hit that point.

```
Public Sub Tester()
    Const NUM As Long = 20
    Const TXT As String = "The quick brown for jumped over the lazy dogs"

    Dim colors, i, l

    colors = Array(vbRed, vbBlue)

    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

        For i = 1 To NUM
            l = Len(.Value)
            'Error here if trying to access characters after ~250     
            With .Characters(Start:=l + 1, Length:=Len(TXT) + 1)
                .Text = TXT & vbLf
                .Font.Color = colors(i Mod 2)
            End With
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```